# Como encontro a primeira terça-feira de um mês?! (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou a realizar o seguinte exercício:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As tabelas são as seguintes :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já tenho o seguinte código:

```
SELECT NOME
FROM CLIENTES C,VENDAS V, LIVROS L
WHERE V.CODIGO_CLIENTE=C.CODIGO_CLIENTE AND L.CODIGO_LIVRO=V.CODIGO_LIVRO AND TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DATA_VENDA,'HH24'))<17 AND GENERO='Informática'
```

Mas não estou a ver nenhuma maneira de obter a primeira terça-feira do mês, alguém me consegue explicar a parte do código que me falta?!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm    dica use uma combinação de trunc e next_day

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar as funções de data do Oracle por exemplo `DAYNAME()` se você comparar `DAYNAME([sua_data])` = 'TUESDAY' irá retornar apenas terça feira. Em seguida limite usando `LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

Fiz esta solução para `Sql Server` porque é o banco que tenho instalado aqui no trabalho, mas acho que você consegue converter para `PL Sql` fácilmente, só não faço porque não teria como testar.

```
declare @weekdays table(id int, name varchar(10))

insert into @weekdays values (1, 'Sunday')
insert into @weekdays values (2, 'Monday')
insert into @weekdays values (3, 'Tuesday')
insert into @weekdays values (4, 'Wednesday')
insert into @weekdays values (5, 'Thursday')
insert into @weekdays values (6, 'Friday')
insert into @weekdays values (7, 'Saturday')

declare @data date = getdate() //usei data de hoje como exemplo
declare @inimonth date = dateadd(day, (day(@data)-1) * -1, @data)
declare @weekidDayOne int = 0

select top 1 @weekidDayOne = id from @weekdays where name = datename(dw, @inimonth)

select case when @weekidDayOne < 3 then dateadd(day, (3 - @weekidDayOne), @inimonth)
            when @weekidDayOne > 3 then dateadd(day, (7 - (@weekidDayOne - 3)), @inimonth)
            else @inimonth
        end
```

Usei uma variável `Table` porque precisava dos números para calcular, se você quiser fazer diferente, talvez fique melhor.

Versão sem variáveis, usando apenas `query`

```
select case when weekdays.weekIniMonth < 3 then dateadd(day, (3 - weekdays.weekIniMonth), weekdays.inimonth)
            when weekdays.weekIniMonth > 3 then dateadd(day, (7 - (weekdays.weekIniMonth - 3)), weekdays.inimonth)
            else weekdays.inimonth
        end firstTueday, weekdays.*
from (
select case when datename(dw, datas.inimonth) = 'Sunday' then 1
            when datename(dw, datas.inimonth) = 'Monday' then 2
            when datename(dw, datas.inimonth) = 'Tuesday' then 3
            when datename(dw, datas.inimonth) = 'Wednesday' then 4
            when datename(dw, datas.inimonth) = 'Thursday' then 5
            when datename(dw, datas.inimonth) = 'Friday' then 6
            when datename(dw, datas.inimonth) = 'Saturday' then 7 end weekIniMonth, datas.*
from (select dateadd(day, (day('2017-07-14')-1) * -1, '2017-07-14') iniMonth) datas) weekdays
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pelas respostas, já encontrei a resolução final do meu problema.

```
SELECT NOME
FROM CLIENTES C,VENDAS V, LIVROS L
WHERE V.CODIGO_CLIENTE=C.CODIGO_CLIENTE AND L.CODIGO_LIVRO=V.CODIGO_LIVRO 
AND TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DATA_VENDA,'HH24'))<17 AND GENERO='Informática' 
AND TO_CHAR(DATA_VENDA,'YYYY.MM.DD')=TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(DATA_VENDA,'Day')-1,'TERÇA-FEIRA'),'YYYY.MM.DD');
```